# Properly Rotate and Align X axis Text in dc.js HeatMap

Tags: javascript, css, heatmap, dc.js

What if in th X axis I have multiple strings with different length ! how to let those strings to be drawn starting from each first char ? If I use
`.attr('dy', '+50')` the result wont be bad but not the desired ! because of the different length of each String ...

```
chart.selectAll("g.cols.axis text") 
 .attr('dy', '+50') 
 .attr("transform", function () { var coord = this.getBBox();
 var x = coord.x + (coord.width / 2), 
     y = coord.y + (coord.height / 2); 
  return "rotate(90 " + x + " " + y + ")" }) 
  .style("fill", "blue");
```

[image]

here is a working example : [jsfiddle.net/5mt77e0o/2](http://jsfiddle.net/5mt77e0o/2) Please note that names and values are randomly generated !

Comment: can you provide your codes in jsfiddle?

Comment: here is a working example : http://jsfiddle.net/5mt77e0o/2/  Please note that names and values are randomly generated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the problem is that when I give the `.style("text-anchor","unset");` the transform wont work properly and particularity the x :

```
 chart
 .selectAll("g.cols.axis text")
 .attr("transform", function () {
 var coord = this.getBBox();
 var x = coord.x + (coord.width / 2),
y = coord.y + (coord.height / 2);
return "rotate(90 " + x + " " + y + ")"
 })
 .style("fill", "blue").style("text-anchor","unset");
```

the right x values must be :

[image]

but instead I'am getting those values :

[image]

[image]

Can it be that setting "text-anchor" to "unset" affects the calcul of x ?

Edit :

In order to fix this I got this trick. 
keep the `.style("text-anchor", "middle")` so that x and y for the rotation can be properly calculated and then at the end change the CSS to "text-anchor : unset" with `.style("text-anchor", "unset");`

```
 chart
   .selectAll("g.cols.axis text")
   .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("transform", function () {
    var coord = this.getBBox();
    var x = coord.x + (coord.width / 2),
    y = coord.y + (coord.height / 2);
  return "rotate(90 " + x + " " + y + ")"
     })
 .style("fill", "blue").style("text-anchor", "unset");
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try below the codes.

Set the **text-anchor:middle** to **text-anchor:unset** and increase the svg height.

```
 .attr("text-anchor", "middle");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5mt77e0o/3/

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! It works bizarrely in JSFIDDLE but not in my project !   Can it be a CSS conflict with something else ?

Comment: You have to set height into svg element.